# Accessing fragment components in OnCreateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to show a Toast when a button in a fragment is pressed, but when reaching the `return view` statement, the app crashes.

I'm simply referencing the components in the OnCreateView method.

MyFragment.java:

```
package com.example.motassem.navdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Motassem on 9/17/2015.
 */
public class FragmentUpdateCard extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText etFirstName, etLastName, etCardNumber, etExpMonth, etExpYear, etCVC;
    private Button btnUpdate;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_update_card, container, false);
        etFirstName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_fname);
        etLastName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_lname);
        etExpMonth = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_card_exp_month);
        etExpYear = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_card_exp_year);
        etCardNumber = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_card_number);
        etCVC = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_card_cvc);

        btnUpdate = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        com.stripe.android.model.Card card = new com.stripe.android.model.Card(
                etCardNumber.getText().toString(),
                Integer.parseInt(etExpMonth.getText().toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(etExpYear.getText().toString()),
                etCVC.getText().toString());

        if (!card.validateCard()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fdsfsdfsfsdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

layout.xml which is a form to collect credit card information

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:paddingTop="26dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_update_fname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="First Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_update_lname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Last Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_update_card_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Card Number"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_update_card_exp_month"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Expiry Month"
                        android:inputType="number" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/input_update_card_exp_year"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Expiry Year"
                        android:inputType="number" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/input_update_card_cvc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="CVC"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_update"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Update Card Information" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**
Logcat

```
09-17 20:08:48.988    5146-5146/com.example.motassem.navdrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.motassem.navdrawer, PID: 5146
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
            at com.example.motassem.navdrawer.FragmentUpdateCard.onClick(FragmentUpdateCard.java:45)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: is it so hard to post error stacktrace or error message you receive?

Comment: logcat??????????????

Comment: how is it possible that return v is throwing an exception ? Get rid of the try- catch. Please.

Comment: etExpMonth or etExpYear is empty. If you give empty string to parseInt method, exception will occur. Check these params or don't call onclick method if they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should only access your controls and add your event listeners in the `onViewCreated` method. Unless the UI builder is complaining about problems with your layout, it should work OK. So, check there as well.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Comment: Well, first of all thank you for the info. The error was that I'm not checking for empty values.

Answer (score 0):

1. your `onCreateView` needs to return the view created by the first inflate method call.  the 2nd one is not needed and actually creates another view (which children) that don't match up to your findviewbyid calls (etFirstName, etLastName, etc...)
2. the click listener needs to handle bad data,  in the stacktrace you posted above, the system is trying to convert a blank string to a number, causing the `NumberFormatException` you are seeing. Instead try validating the entered fields or handling the exception so you app doesnt crash. Or trying using a [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePickerFragment) (so you dont have to figure out bad dates, like Feb 31st, on your own)
3. the click listener that makes a toast can be inlined using `new View.OnClickListener()` (optional)

Here is an example of all (minus the [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePickerFragment) stuff).

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_update_card, container, false);
    etFirstName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_fname);
    etLastName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_lname);
    etExpMonth = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_card_exp_month);
    etExpYear = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_card_exp_year);
    etCardNumber = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_card_number);
    etCVC = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_update_card_cvc);

    btnUpdate = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);

    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                com.stripe.android.model.Card card =
                    new com.stripe.android.model.Card(etCardNumber.getText().toString(),
                                                      Integer.parseInt(etExpMonth.getText().toString()),
                                                      Integer.parseInt(etExpYear.getText().toString()),
                                                      etCVC.getText().toString());
                String message = "card valid";
                if (!card.validateCard()) {
                    message = "card not valid!";
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                message = "Enter in a correct date!!!";
            }
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

Comment: Sorry it was my fault I forgot to delete those two. I tried your solution before but faced the same issue.

Comment: @MotassemJa  thx for adding the logcat,  see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

The actual crash is due to invalid integer in your inputs. You can just catch `NumberFormatException` when constructing your card object in your `onClick` and fail to something reasonable.